# Backbone.js: Rendering json data in a model

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

OK, super basic Backbone question - I've been searching all round for this, but am just too slow to get it despite a multitude of similar questions. Rest assured I am suitably ashamed.

Anyway, enough self-flagellation - why doesn't this render?

```
var app = app || {};

app.Option = Backbone.Model.extend({
url: 'http://localhost:4711/api'

//This url contains the following JSON: {"title": "Blahblah", "author": "Luke Skywalker"};  
});

 app.View = Backbone.View.extend({

el: 'body',

initialize: function(){
    this.model.fetch();
    this.model.bind('change', this.render(), this);
},

render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.model.get('title'));
    return this;
}

});


$(function() {

 var option = new app.Option();
    this.homeView = new app.View({   //Tried changing this to a standard var declaration but didn't work
      model: option
    });
    this.homeView.render();
});
```

So I'm expecting to see the JSON "Blahblah" on the screen, but I see nothing. The JSON is being fetched correctly (I can see the successful GET request in the firebug console) and I think I've ensured the data is fetched before I attempt to render it...

So what's wrong? The console is giving me this error: "TypeError: (intermediate value).callback.call is not a function"

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing is that you're calling `this.render()` immediately in your event binding rather than just binding the callback. Do this instead (using `listenTo` for best practices):

```
initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    this.model.fetch();
}
```

Is it possible that the model is not actually changing? You might try to bind to `sync` instead of `change` to see if that works.

You also render twice. Once directly with `this.homeView.render()` and once via the event handler. If you really want to keep your model fetch in `initialize` and bind to the change event you don't need the direct render.

Play with those and see if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: To be clear the most important part of this is the `this.render()` in your event listener which should be `this.render` .

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the parentheses from the render method while binding:

`this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);`

Also using `on` or `listenTo` is a better approach then `bind`.

Answer (score 1):

I would construct the backbone skeleton in the following way:

```
var app = app || {};

app.Option.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});

app.Option.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({       
   model : app.Option.Model,

   fetch : function(options) {     
       Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
   },

   url : function() {
       return 'http://localhost:4711/api';
   },

   parse: function(response) { // this is the ajax call
      console.log(response);
   }
});
```

Then in View just call the fetch method on initialize:

```
app.Option.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    collection : app.Option.Collection,

    initialize : {
       this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this); 
       this.collection.fetch();
    },

    render : {
       var results = this.collection.toJSON(); 
       console.log(results);
    }
});
```

This is my minimal backbone skeleton when i need to call a webservice. I haven't tested locally, but this way the code should work.